# How do I show that the following solution is stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, stability-theory

I want to solve the following exercise:

*Determine the stability properties of the following solution:*
$$
(\cos t, \sin t) \text{ of }\,\begin{align}\dot{x} &= -y(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}\\\dot{y} &= x(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}\end{align}
$$

**What I've tried:** I tried to expand this system around its solution $(\cos t, \sin t)$ and examine the eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix. We have 
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}-y(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}\\x(x^2 + y^2)^{-1/2}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial(x,y)} = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{xy}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} & -\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\\\dfrac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} & -\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+ y^2)^{3/2}}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The linear expansion is given by
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{y}\end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{\partial f(\cos t, \sin t)}{\partial (x,y)}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} + \text{ higher order terms}
\end{align}
where 
$$
\dfrac{\partial f(\cos t, \sin t)}{\partial (x,y)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos t\sin t & -\cos^2t\\\sin^2t & -\cos t \sin t\end{bmatrix}
$$
Unfortunately the coefficient matrix $\dfrac{\partial f(\cos t, \sin t)}{\partial (x,y)}$ is singular (its determinant is zero) and the critical point is degenerate. I therefore cannot say anything about the stability of the solution based on the eigenvalues. I've looked at the answer in my textbook and apparently this solution *is* stable. I just don't know how to show it.

**Question:** How do I show that this solution is stable?

Comment: Use Lyaponv function.

Comment: The system in polar coordinates is $(\dot \rho, \dot \phi) = (0, 1/\rho)$. The solution $(\rho, \phi) = (1, t)$ is stable (in the sense that the distance between trajectories remains small) but not asymptotically stable.